# Use inline text on Bootstrap input element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way of lining up the **Remove** and the input control, and not have it on a different line?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5w4w3zy/)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint" placeholder="Via 1"> Remove
```

Comment: Use a proper `label`...that's what they are for.

Comment: Also, bootstrap is telling the input to be 100% wide...so you'd have to adjust that.

Comment: Check: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap is telling the input to be 100% wide...so you'd have to adjust that.

[**JSfiddle With Bootstrap Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s5w4w3zy/4/)

```css
input.form-control.booking.waypoint {
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint" placeholder="Via 1"/>
<label for="">Remove</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#remove{
    display:inline;
}

.booking{
    width:50%;
    display:inline;
}

<input type="text" class="form-control booking waypoint" placeholder="Via 1"> <p id="remove">Remove</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.col-any class name`.

For text box

> col-lg-7

and for label

> .col-lg-5